# Issue during update azure vmss trough rest api using curl

Tags: azure, api, curl

I'd like to change a VMSS capacity through API. On the Azure webpage there is a "Try it" button for check a request:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machine-scale-sets/update?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0

and my JSON is working fine from that link. But with curl I've got an answer:

"code":"UnsupportedResourceOperation","message":"The resource type 'virtualMachineScaleSets' does not support this operation."

My request looks like this:

```
curl -s -X PATCH \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
  -H "Content-type: application/json" \
  -d @body.json \
  https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${SUBSCRIPTION}/resourceGroups/${RG}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/${SCALE_SET_NAME}?api-version=2022-11-01
```

and the content of a body.json file is:

```
{
  "sku": {
  "tier": "Standard",
  "capacity": 1,
  "name": "Standard_B2s"
  }
}
```

The same json body is working fine on "Try it" so it may be something wrong with my curl request. I'm able to GET information using curl. Could you please show me where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an  **Azure AD Application and added API permissions**  like below:

[image]

Now, I generated  **auth-code**  using below authorize endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

Now, I generated  **access token**  by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://management.azure.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

By using the above token,  *I am able to update the VMSS successfully*  like below:

```json
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/RGName/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/vmss?api-version=2023-03-01

{
"sku": {
"tier": "Standard",
"capacity": 1,
"name": "Standard_B2s"
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My bad of course. The API version what I used in the example was `2022-11-01` instead of the latest `2023-03-01` and I used a `SCALE_SET_NAME` which was not defined on my host machine.